# Why does my bool method return true but then not return true when called from other scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, return-type

I'm working on a project with a player character and enemy characters that have a public float variable called "hp" in a class called "DamageDetector". Variable hp decrements based off of the damage of an attack. In the same "DamageDetector" class I also have a bool method "IsDead()" that returns true when a character's "hp" is less than or equal to 0:

```
    `//Method for detecting if the character is dead or not
     public bool IsDead()
     {
         //Return true if hp is less than or equal to 0, otherwise return false
         return hp <= 0;
     }`
```

In a separate class called "EnemyGroup" I call upon the "IsDead()" method from class "DamageDetector" to check if an enemy has died so that I can remove it from a list of GameObjects called "enemies":

```
    `//A public list to store enemies in a contained group
    public List<GameObject> enemies = new List<GameObject>();

    //Called every frame
    private void Update()
    {
        //For each enemy in the group
        foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies)
        {
            //If the enemy is dead
            if (enemy.GetComponentInParent<DamageDetector>().IsDead())
            {
                //Remove the enemy from the list
                enemies.Remove(enemy);
            }
        }
    }`
```

When I attach to unity to debug, "hp" depletes as expected from attacks and the "IsDead()" method returns true in the "DamageDetector" class.  But for some reason the "IsDead()" method does not return true in the "EnemyGroup" class when checked by the if statement in the foreach loop.  I noticed that it also doesn't return true when checked in other classes.

Any help would be much appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: The other things aren't dead?

Comment: Try making the hp variable public and checking to see what it is from other classes. Let us know it is. Quite interesting, since that seems to that it should work just fine.
Btw, the `GetComponentInParent` or any `GetComponent` function is quite slow especially when you call it every frame, so I recommend to save the enemies in terms of their instances of the DamageDetector and not as GameObjects.

Comment: Looks like you're checking two different instances of the component in two different classes. If you add the hp <= 0 in the update instead of using the isDead it will probably show that the hp is above 0 on that component.

Check if your enemies list is properly populated and that the getComponentInParent is really what you want. And that it really returns the component that you expect it to return.

Comment: @kostis1101 hp already is public, but good point about the GetComponentInParent being called for each loop.  I was actually planning on changing that after I got it to work.

Comment: @Lieke Okay thanks I'll try checking if hp <= 0  works right in the update later tonight when I get a chance to work on it, and I'll let you know what happens.  You're saying to do that instead of using the IsDead method?  I thought it would be more efficient to use the IsDead method instead so that I'm not checking it every frame for each character on screen.  Also the enemies list is filled correctly when I look at it in the inspector.  How would you go about debugging/checking that the GetComponentInParent is actually getting the DamageDetector?

Comment: @Lieke IsDead is not returning true in the loop to remove the enemy from the list even though it's returning true in the DamageDetector to kill the enemy.

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't quite understand what you're asking, could you elaborate more to explain what you mean?

Comment: @kostis1101 I will check the status of the hp variable from other classes as well.

Comment: @kostis1101 So for some reason it works if I just check if (hp <= 0) instead of checking if (IsDead()).  I'll probably go with this but it's confusing why IsDead() doesn't return true when called from other scripts.  I read somewhere in another post that when bool methods aren't declared as static, they won't return true from a separate class.  Which from my understanding that wouldn't work because I have multiple instances of the character objects so it couldn't be static.

Comment: where did you read that? I don't think that should be the case...